# Adding a value to a certain key

Tags: python

```
lst_in=['Пушкин: Сказака о рыбаке и рыбке', 'Есенин: Письмо к женщине', 'Тургенев: Муму', 'Пушкин: Евгений Онегин', 'Есенин: Русь']
D = [(L.split(": ")[0], L.split(": ")[1]) for L in lst_in]
print(D)
d = {}
for i in D:
    x,y = i[0],i[1]
    if x not in d:
        d[x] = {y}
    else:
        d[x].add(y)
```

Is there any other way to add a value to a particular key?

Comment: Maybe you want a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries have a very useful *setdefault* function which you could use like this:

```
lst_in = [
    'Пушкин: Сказака о рыбаке и рыбке',
    'Есенин: Письмо к женщине',
    'Тургенев: Муму',
    'Пушкин: Евгений Онегин',
    'Есенин: Русь'
    ]

d = {}

for x, y in (L.split(': ') for L in lst_in):
    d.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)
    
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Пушкин': {'Евгений Онегин', 'Сказака о рыбаке и рыбке'}, 'Есенин': {'Письмо к женщине', 'Русь'}, 'Тургенев': {'Муму'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with `dict.setdefault`.

```
d = {}
for x, y in D:
    d.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)
```

---

You're iterating twice on the same thing, one on `lst_in`, one on `D`, you can do it in once :

```
d = {}
for L in lst_in:
    x, y = L.split(": ", maxsplit=1)
    d.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)
```

---

`defaultdict` is also an option

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for L in lst_in:
    x, y = L.split(": ", maxsplit=1)
    d[x].add(y)
```

Comment: Looks like default `{y}` might not just be shorter but also [faster](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3m9KK8nMVSjJzUzNLFDJzC_KLShSKUgtSE0u4uNLyixRSFTLzFKLVi1NLNDT1ElNSNCo11XUU1Ksra2G8WAUtBWMrLgUgKFGwVcjNzNOAGKCRqqOgVGmrfmH-xeaLHRd2XdhxYa-6kqYmWGlBUWZeiUaJjkKqJsQlUAfBHAYA).